# How to output array via ECO in DocPad to build for example an image gallery?

Tags: docpad

I have a document with the following frontmatter:

```
---
layout: default
title: "A Gallery"
image:
    - "image-1.jpg"
    - "image-2.jpg"
    - "image-3.jpg"
---
```

Now I want to build a list of images in my default-template like this.

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="image-1.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="image-2.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="image-3.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

I found this [tutorial for javascript loops](http://www.sebarmeli.com/blog/2010/12/06/best-way-to-loop-through-an-array-in-javascript/).

But how do I convert it to ECO/Coffeescript?

Something like this?

```
<ul>
<% gallery i + 1, for images i in @document.image[i]: %>
  <li><%- @document.image[i] %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

In your `docpad.coffee` file:

```
site:
  pics:
    myFirstGallery: [
      {name: '/images/mypic.png' h: '180px' w: '100px'},
      {name: '/images/mypic2.png' h: '180px' w: '100px'}
    ]
```

Then in your eco file:

```
<ul>
  <% for pic in @document.site.pics.myFirstGallery: %>
    <li>
      <img src="#{pic.name}" width="#{pic.w}" height="#{pic.h}" />
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

It should be something similar to that. I use Jade so I forget the exact CoffeeScript syntax. Let me know if I got something wrong. The `for in` syntax comes from [CoffeeScript's](http://coffeescript.org/) website. I looked it up on [Eco's ReadMe](https://github.com/sstephenson/eco) file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after seeing this code in [»The Little Book on CoffeeScript« (GitHub Version)](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/02_syntax.html).

```
for name, i in ["Roger the pickpocket", "Roderick the robber"]
  alert "#{i} - Release #{name}"
```

For the sample above (see my question) you have to write this code.

```
<ul>
  <% for image, i in @document.image: %>
    <li>
       <img src="<%- "#{image}" %>" />
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Now it works like charm.